# one application with two database in heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, sequelpro

I want to create one more database in current application served by heroku (database is clearDB and its management is sequel pro).

In heroku config, I tried to set Environment variables like DATABASE_SECOND_URL, dbname2, etc, however, couldn't add database in sequel pro: Access denied for user xxxx database xxxx.

If you have an idea to solve this problem, it would be appreciated to share with me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get database info
   heroku pg
   -> Gave me the name of the database
   eg: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
2. Reset the database on heroku
   heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
3. Look for the name of the local database

   - Opened config/database.yml and found the database
     name for the development environment.
     eg: fashions_development => put the name that the terminal give it to you
4. Run push the local database to Heroku
   Opened config/database.yml and found the database
   heroku pg:push fashions_development HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN

Comment: I use clearDB database,  so have no heroku-postgresql databases.